# Simple calculations in Macro Variables - any way to use the MOD(,) function?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Is there a clever way to use the `MOD(,)` function while defining Macro Variables?

For example consider this:

```
%LET year=2015;
%LET dec = %EVAL(mod(&year.,100));
```

Where `dec` will just contain the last two digits of the year. This will not work (the same with `SYSEVAL`), since the `%EVAL` function cannot access the `MOD` function properly.

I don't want to include a `DATA STEP`, but the result should actually be something like this:

```
data _null_;
input_year=2015;
input_dec =mod(input_year,100);
%LET year=input_year;
%LET dec = input_dec;
put &dec. 'and ' &year.;
run;
```

The problem here is that the Macro Variables cannot be called outside of the `DATA STEP` (maybe I did something wrong? Even the `global option` doesn't do the trick).

**Some context:**

In an existing `autoexec file` the user has to change some input, depending on the year, all together 3 Macro Variables have to be adapted (year, dec, and the follow up year). My idea was to infer the other changes from just one input, the year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%eval` and `%sysevalf` are used to do calculations on numbers, outside of a data step.  When using functions then you need `%sysfunc`

```
%LET year=2015;
%LET dec = %sysfunc(mod(&year.,100));

%put &=dec. and &=year.;
```

Comment: Great, that works! Not sure why I didn't spot the `%sysfunc` function right from the beginning. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use SYSFUNC() to use functions in macro syntax. SUBSTR will work as well.

```
%let year=2015;
%let index = %sysfunc(substr(&year, 3, 2));

%put &year;
%put &index.;
```

%EVAL() works for mathematical calculations, such as:

```
%let next_year = %eval(&year + 1);
%let next_year_index = %eval(&index + 1);

%put Next Year: &next_year.;
%put Next Year Index: &next_year_index;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reeza provided a nice solution which is absolutely correct. I'd expand it by two comments:
 1. You can find functions like %SUBSTR in SAS, but those operate on *macrovariables* only; they do not replace `%sysfunc(substr())`, on the contrary.
 2. It is useful to take a minute and go through the list of macrofunctions, i.e. those that begin with percent sign: you will see that apart from %EVAL(), there is also %SYSEVALF(). The list is [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p06poki1icvtx7n19uf8jnx20pjb.htm).